# MinGW can't find GLFW libraries

Tags: mingw

Hi guys need some help getting MinGW to link GLFW's libraries. I can't find any answers on the web or rather not any that I can understand. I have tried to specify the path to the libs folder using -L and I have added the lib's and include's to MinGW's.

I have even tried changing the names of the libs. The compiler never complains about not finding the headers but the linker says it cant find whatever lib I specify.
 I have been at GLFW's site but I'm afraid that I don't understand much of what they are trying to tell me. I'm on windows7 using MinGW via the command line since I can't get it to work with Code::Blocks either. I have tried following the installation instructions on opengl-tutorial.org but that sadly starts to complain about something to do with ANT which I don't understand at all. So I think I have a better chance at getting it to work via the command line.

I have tried:

```
g++ test.cpp -lglfw or g++ test.cpp -LC:\GLFW\lib -lglfw
```

into the command line.

Comment: Ok guys after 2 days of fruitlessly trying to get GLFW3 to work I decided to download GLFW-2.7.7 . I did every thing the same as for GLFW3 and it worked, I compiled my test program with ease using GLFW-2.7.7. Now my question is: Why doesn't GLFW3 work with MinGW.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make mingw32 and GLFW3 to work together.

1. Be sure you have consistent librairies (32 or 64 bits) (it wasn't my case)
2. Rename glfw3dll.a to libglfw3dll.a
3. Add you lib*.a from glfw to %MINGW_BASE%\lib and include files to %MINGW_BASE%\include
4. Compile and link using g++ test.cpp -lglfw3 -lopengl32
5. To run it, be sure to add glfw3.dll in System32 or/and SysWOW64

It worked for me

Hope it will help,

Answer (score 1):

A simple investigate of the GLFW3's `lib-mingw` directory holds the answer for your question. Say you've GLFW3's binary package, from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/glfw/files/glfw/3.0.3/) (one of `glfw-3.0.3.bin.WIN64.zip` or `glfw-3.0.3.bin.WIN32.zip` depending on your toolchain). Extracting it should've given a directory `lib-mingw` amongst others. This directory contains:

- libglfw3.a
- glfw3dll.a
- glfw3.dll

Thus the library name is `glfw3` and not just `glfw`. So when passing it to the linker, you've to pass `-lglfw3` i.e. if you want to statically link to it. If you want to link to it dynamically, then just pass `glfw3dll.a`; adding the `-l` will lead to the linker prefixing it with `lib` and suffixing it with `.a` (see Django's answer).